# Unable to display Images from Django Imagefield

Tags: django, django-2.0, imagefield

I am able to load images to the specific path using Imagefield but not able to display those images in my html templates.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfRyh.png)

my settings.py :

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/app/static/"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join( BASE_DIR,'app','static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

files are loading successfully @ ./media/

here is my urlpattern setting:
if settings.DEBUG:

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

```
 {% for service in services %}
    <div class="col-md-4 animate-box">
        <div class="feature-left">
            <span class="icon">
            <img src="{{ service.icon.url }}" alt=""/>
            </span>
            <div class="feature-copy">
            <h3>{{service.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{ service.text }}</p>
            <p><a href="#">Learn More <i class="icon-arrow-right22"></i></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}

Not Found: /icon/6.png
Not Found: /icon/blog-1.jpg
Not Found: /media/6_qjtYB6t.png
Not Found: /blog/blog-3.jpg
```

Comment: Add your model class to the question.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ service.icon.url }}" alt=""/>
```

Comment: Tried but not working!  error : The 'icon' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: Have the pictures loaded correctly in the "media" directory?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your attention. however I've solved the issue using a if tag. This is working now.

```
{% for service in services %}
  <div class="col-md-4 animate-box">
    <div class="feature-left">
      <span class="">
        {% if service.icon %}
        <img src="{{service.icon.url}}" alt=""/>
        {% endif %}
      </span>
    <div class="feature-copy">
        <h3>{{service.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{ service.text }}</p>
        <p><a href="#">Learn More <i class="icon-arrow-right22"></i></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```